# what's wrong in using interrupt handlers as event listeners

Tags: c, embedded, arm, bare-metal

My system is simple enough that it runs without an OS, I simply use interrupt handlers like I would use event listener in a desktop program. In everything I read online, people try to spend as little time as they can in interrupt handlers, and give the control back to the tasks. But I don't have an OS or real task system, and I can't really find design information on OS-less targets.

I have basically one interrupt handler that reads a chunk of data from the USB and write the data to memory, and one interrupt handler that reads the data, sends the data on GPIO and schedule itself on an hardware timer again.

What's wrong with using the interrupts the way I do, and using the NVIC (I use a cortex-M3) to manage the work hierarchy ?

Comment: How do you mean with "using as event listener"? What would you do in your interrupt handler?

Comment: Typically, you have multiple interrupts in a system.  The CPU can not handle multiple interrupt routines at a time.  The stuff in the interrupt handler can be highly critical.  For instance, a UART may have a 8 character FIFO.  If you delay reading, with some other interrupt, you loose characters.  This can be a critical mistake.  For a no OS system with a single interrupt, you maybe fine.  However, it won't scale well.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, in the context of this question, let's refer to the OS as a *scheduler*.

Now, unlike threads, interrupt service routines are "above" the scheduling scheme.

In other words, the scheduler has no "control" over them.

An ISR enters execution as a result of a HW interrupt, which sets the PC to a different address in the code-section (more precisely, to the interrupt-vector, where you "do a few things" before calling the ISR).

Hence, essentially, the priority of any ISR is higher than the priority of the thread with the highest priority.

So one obvious reason to spend as little time as possible in an ISR, is the "side effect" that ISRs have on the scheduling scheme that you design for your system.

Since your system is purely interrupt-driven (i.e., no scheduler and no threads), this is not an issue.

However, if nested ISRs are not allowed, then interrupts must be disabled from the moment an interrupt occurs and until the corresponding ISR has completed. In that case, if any interrupt occurs while an ISR is in execution, then your program will effectively ignore it.

So the longer you spend inside an ISR, the higher the chances are that you'll "miss out" on an interrupt.

Comment: Grammar question - in the last sentence, do I need to add "are" after "chances"?

Comment: "delay it" rather then "ignore it" in most cases.  w.r.t. "higher are" - I don't think so.  Either "the higher the chances" or "the chances are higher".

Comment: @Clifford: Delay it until when? What if many other interrupts are delayed? At some point it will run out of "buffer space" for those delayed interrupts, which will be ignored thereafter... Regarding that last sentence, please read it over, I had to consult with an (ex) English girlfriend on that one, I think it's pretty well constructed... Second thought, perhaps I should put the "are" after the "chances"... or perhaps remove it altogether...

Comment: By "delay", I am referring to the *normal* hardware implementation whereby an interrupt flag will be set for some peripheral or GPIO, but while interrupts are disabled, the interrupt will not be serviced.  If the interrupts are then re-enabled, and the pending flag is set, the interrupt will occur immediately but *delayed* w.r.t. the original event.  It will only be "ignored" if all interrupt pending flags are cleared before re-enabling interrupts.  If an interrupt source occurs twice or more while disabled, that will indeed be ignored, there is no buffering, and no interrupt counting.

Answer (score 3):

In many desktop programs, events are send to queue and there is some "event loop" that handle this queue. This event loop handles event by event so it is not possible to interrupt one event by other one. It also is good practise in event driven programming to have all event handlers as short as possible because they are not interruptable.

In bare metal programming, interrupts are similar to events but they are not send to queue.

- execution of interrupt handlers is not sequential, they can be interrupted by interrupt with higher priority (numerically lower number in Cortex-M3)
- there is no queue of same interrupts - e.g. you can't detect multiple GPIO interrupts while  you are in that interrupt - this is the reason you should have all routines as short as possible.

It is possible to implement queues by yourself, feed these queues by interrupts and consume these queues in your super loop (consume while disabling all interrupts). By this approach, you can get sequential processing of interrupts. If you keep your handlers short, this is mostly not needed and you can do the work in handlers directly.

It is also good practise in OS based systems that they are using queues, semaphores and "interrupt handler tasks" to handle interrupts.

Answer (score 2):

With bare metal it is perfectly fine to design for application bound or interrupt/event bound so long as you do your analysis.  So if you know what events/interrupts are coming at what rate and you can insure that you will handle all of them in the desired/designed amount of time, you can certainly take your time in the event/interrupt handler rather than be quick and send a flag to the foreground task.

The common approach of course is to get in and out fast, saving just enough info to handle the thing in the foreground task.  The foreground task has to spin its wheels of course looking for event flags, prioritizing, etc.

You could of course make it more complicated and when the interrupt/event comes, save state, and return to the forground handler in the forground mode rather than interrupt mode.

Now that is all general but specific to the cortex-m3 I dont think there are really modes like big brother ARMs.  So long as you take a real-time approach and make sure your handlers are deterministic, and you do your system engineering and insure that no situation happens where the events/interrupts stack up such that the response is not deterministic, not too late or too long or loses stuff it is okay

Comment: how do you do your analysis? I know there is a time bond, but how do I find it, and how do I find the admissible one?

Comment: @nraynaud : If your interrupt scheme is priority based an preemptive, you should use [Rate Monotonic Scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate-monotonic_scheduling) - shortest process gets highest priority, so the long-slow stuff can always be interrupted by the short-fast stuff.

Comment: then I need to get an OS to implement the concepts of scheduling and tasks, and switch?

Answer (score 2):

What you have to ask yourself is whether all events can be services in time in all circumstances:

For example;

- If your interrupt system were run-to-completion, will the servicing of one interrupt cause unacceptable delay in the servicing of another?
- On the other hand, if the interrupt system is priority-based and preemptive, will the servicing of a high priority interrupt unacceptably delay a lower one?

In the latter case, you could use Rate Monotonic Analysis to assign priorities to assure the greatest responsiveness (the shortest execution-time handlers get the highest priority).  In the first case your system may lack a degree of determinism, and performance will be variable under both event load, and code changes.

One approach is to divide the handler into real-time critical and non-critical sections, the time-critical code can be done in the handler, then a flag set to prompt the non-critical action to be performed in the "background" non-interrupt context in a "big-loop" system that simply polls event flags or shared data for work to complete.  Often all that might be necessary in the interrupt handler is to copy some data to timestamp some event - making data available for background processing without holding up processing of new events.

For more sophisticated scheduling, there are a number of simple, low-cost or free RTOS schedulers that provide multi-tasking, synchronisation, IPC and timing services with very small footprints and can run on very low-end hardware.  If you have a hardware timer and 10K of code space (sometimes less), you can deploy an RTOS.

Answer (score 2):

**I am taking your described problem first**

As I interpret it your goal is to create a device which by receiving commands from the USB, outputs some GPIO, such as LEDs, relays etc. For **this** simple task, your approach seems to be fine (if the USB layer can work with it adequately).

A prioritizing problem exists though, in this case it may be that if you overload the USB side (with data from the other end of the cable), and the interrupt handling it is higher priority than that triggered by the timer, handling the GPIO, the GPIO side may miss ticks (like others explained, interrupts can't queue).

In your case this is about what could be considered.

**Some general guidance**

For the *"spend as little time in the interrupt handler as possible"* the rationale is just what others told: an OS may realize a queue, etc., however hardware interrupts offer no such concepts. If the event causing the interrupt happens, the CPU enters your handler. Then until you handle it's source (such as reading a receive holding register in the case of a UART), you lose any further occurrences of that event. After this point, until exiting the handler, you may receive whether the event happened, but not how many times (if the event happened again while the CPU was still processing the handler, the associated interrupt line goes active again, so after you return from the handler, the CPU immediately re-enters it provided nothing higher priority is waiting).

Above I described the general concept observable on 8 bit processors and the AVR 32bit (I have experience with these).

When designing such low-level systems (no OS, one "background" task, and some interrupts) it is fundamental to understand what goes on on each priority level (if you utilize such). In general, you would make the most real-time critical tasks the highest priority, taking the most care of serving those fast, while being more relaxed with the lower priority levels.

From an other aspect usually at design phase it can be planned how the system should react to missed interrupts, since where there are interrupts, missing one **will** eventually happen anyway. Critical data going across communication lines should have adequate checksums, an especially critical timer should be sourced from a count register, not from event counting, and the likes.

An other nasty part of interrupts is their asynchronous nature. If you fail to design the related locks properly, they will eventually corrupt something giving nightmares to that poor soul who will have to debug it. The *"spend as little time in the interrupt handler as possible"* statement also encourages you to keep the interrupt code reasonably short which means less code to consider for this problem as well. If you also worked with multitasking assisted by an RTOS you should know this part (there are some differences though: a higher priority interrupt handler's code does not need protection against a lower priority handler's).

If you can *properly design your architecture* regarding the necessary asynchronous tasks, getting around without an OS (from the no multitasking aspect) may even prove to be a nicer solution. It needs way more thinking to design it properly, however later there are much less locking related problems. I got through some mid-sized safety critical projects designed over a single background "task" with very few and little interrupts, and the experience and maintenance demands regarding those (especially the tracing of bugs) were quite satisfactory compared to some others in the company built over multitasking concepts.

Comment: it's all about learning, if I'm asking here, it's mostly to discover what I don't know. I can't do an expert analysis job on my system and I can only learn so much information. But I think I got my interrupt priorities in the correct order, and I believe USB handles being left unattended for a few ms no pb.

Comment: It is not some arcane magic I think. To be honest I never did anything what would qualify under the shiny label "expert analysis" either. Usually most interrupt code can be got short enough, and their frequency constrained enough with ease so you won't bring the processor any near to it's knees by "normal" use. Otherwise just stack them up so even in the extreme case your program will bail out in a planned intended manner (and it has enough stack to do so). I could share some stories, but really, I don't think it is something too arcane ;)